# Getting segmentation fault when giving input to structure members on run time

Tags: memory, kernel, gdb

I have written a small code to fetch info of 'n' number of students.
But after running the program, I'm getting a segfault. Please find the code below.

```
struct students
{
     char name[20];
     int age;
     int id;
}student[100];
int main()
{
      int count;
      int no_students;
      printf("Enter no of students");
      scanf("%d",&no_students);
      for (count = 1 ; count <= no_students ; count++)
      {
           printf("Enter the details for student%d\n",count);
           printf("Name:");
           scanf("%s",student[count].name);
           printf("Age:");
           scanf("%d",student[count].age);
           printf("ID:");
           scanf("%d",student[count].id);
      }
      return 0; 
 }

 root@debian:/home/renga/C_code# ./nike
 Enter no of students3
 Enter the details for student1
 Name:renga
 Age:12
 Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Its stackoverflox question :)

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem, missed reference operator in scanf.

```
        printf("Age:");
        scanf("%d",&(student[count].age));
        printf("ID:");
        scanf("%d",&(student[count].id));
```

Comment: And arrays are 0-based, so your for loop is off by one

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the right group to ask C language help/syntax question. I would recommend reading a good C programming language book ex: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html

Having said that, the problem is, you are trying to read your int data type (age & id) values incorrectly. You need to read the values into the address of the variables as shown below...

```
scanf("%d",&student[count].age);
```